# Beautifulsoup search tag through the content of the tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

The following html code:

```
<div class="rating-list">
<ul class="recommend">
<li>
<span class="recommend-titleInline">Stayed April 2013, traveled as a couple</span>
<ul class="recommend-column first">
<li class="recommend-answer">
<span class="rate rate_ss ss50">
<img class="sprite-ratings" src="http://c1.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="5 of 5 stars" content="5.0"/>
</span>
Value</li>
<li class="recommend-answer">
<span class="rate rate_ss ss50">
<img class="sprite-ratings" src="http://c1.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="5 of 5 stars" content="5.0"/>
</span>
Location</li>
<li class="recommend-answer">
<span class="rate rate_ss ss50">
<img class="sprite-ratings" src="http://c1.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="5 of 5 stars" content="5.0"/>
</span>
Sleep Quality</li>
</ul>
<ul class="recommend-column">
<li class="recommend-answer">
<span class="rate rate_ss ss50">
<img class="sprite-ratings" src="http://c1.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="5 of 5 stars" content="5.0"/>
</span>
Rooms</li>
<li class="recommend-answer">
<span class="rate rate_ss ss50">
<img class="sprite-ratings" src="http://c1.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="5 of 5 stars" content="5.0"/>
</span>
Cleanliness</li>
<li class="recommend-answer">
<span class="rate rate_ss ss50">
<img class="sprite-ratings" src="http://c1.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="5 of 5 stars" content="5.0"/>
</span>
Service</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now I have use Beautifulsoup get the whole tag，then i want to get “li”tags like this：

```
valueRatingTag = subRatingListTags[i].find(name = 'li', attrs = { 'class' : 'recommend-answer' }, text = 'Value')
locationRatingTag = subRatingListTags[i].find(name = 'li', attrs = { 'class' : 'recommend-answer' }, text = 'Location')
sleepRatingTag = subRatingListTags[i].find(name = 'li', attrs = { 'class' : 'recommend-answer' }, text = 'Sleep Quality')
        roomRatingTag = subRatingListTags[i].find(name = 'li', attrs = { 'class' : 'recommend-answer' }, text = 'Rooms')
        cleanRatingTag = subRatingListTags[i].find(name = 'li', attrs = { 'class' : 'recommend-answer' }, text = 'Cleanliness')
        serviceRatingTag = subRatingListTags[i].find(name = 'li', attrs = { 'class' : 'recommend-answer' }, text = 'Service')
```

But it seems that fail.the six variables are all None,which is not what i expect.what should i do

Answer (score 0):

Will using a regex as an argument to `text` help?

```
subRatingListTags[i].find(text=re.compile("Location"))
```

The line breaks may cause the exact text matching to fail here.

Comment: In that way， i can only get the string 'Location', rather than the tag <li class="recommend-answer">
<span class="rate rate_ss ss50">
<img class="sprite-ratings" src="http://c1.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="5 of 5 stars" content="5.0"/>
</span>
Location</li>

Answer (score 0):

You're not clear about what you want. Anyway:

```
>>> lis = [t for t in soup.find_all('li', 'recommend-answer')]
>>> lis[0].text
'\n\n\n\nValue'
>>> lis[1].text
'\n\n\n\nLocation'
>>> lis[0].img['alt']
'5 of 5 stars'
```

You definitely want to preprocess the html to remove all linebreaks before starting to parse it.